# Show all Windows Actions like IntelliJ IDEA or VS Code

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, productivity

I want to use mostly the keyboard to control Windows. Since it is hard to remember some rarely used keyboard shortcuts, I'm looking for a way to search and select actions (not only programs by name) by typing the action name.

This approach is known from IntelliJ IDEA or editors like Visual Studio Code or Sublime.

[image]

Ideally the tool to find and execute actions should also display the shortcuts, if available.

Is there a functionality like that included in Windows or is another tool available?

Comment: You may want to reword your question. Currently it's likely to be closed as off-topic (we don't do software recommendations here and some users are sensitive to questions that look like software-rec).

Comment: The only way such a tool could be created is by manually gathering all possible shortcuts/actions and creating a tool using that information. You cannot programmatically ask the operating system or other software for actions.

Comment: @DanielB You can collect items from app's top menu. Dash feature in Unity (the Ubuntu DE) did that.